# PHP Parse error syntax unexpected T_ECHO in line 20

Tags: php, html

I really don't see the error, i am working with PHP and HTML, and i don't know what means a T_ECHO error, please help me with this issue, thanks.
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /home/falconim/public_html/ucsg/tdg2/productos.php on line 20

```
if(mysql_num_rows($allproductos)!=0 ){

$cont=1;
for ($la=0;$la<mysql_num_rows($allproductos);$la++)
    {$id = mysql_result($allproductos,$la,"id");
     $categoria = mysql_result($allproductos,$la,"categoria");
     $nombre = mysql_result($allproductos,$la,"nombre");
     $descripcion = mysql_result($allproductos,$la,"descripcion");
     $imagen = mysql_result($allproductos,$la,"imagen");
     $cantidad = mysql_result($allproductos,$la,"cantidad");
     $precio = mysql_result($allproductos,$la,"precio");
     $descrip=substr($descripcion, 0, 25);
     if($cont==1){
       echo'
<div class="postcontent postcontent-0 clearfix"><div class="content-layout-wrapper layout-item-0">
<div class="content-layout layout-item-1">
<div class="content-layout-row">
<!-- SEPARADOR-->
<div class="layout-cell layout-item-2" style="width: 25%" >
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(128, 0, 30);">
<img width="100" height="77" alt="" class="lightbox" src="'.$imgproductosruta.$imagen.'">
<br></span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(128, 0, 30);">
'.$descrip.'...
<br></span></p><p style="text-align: center;">
<span style="color: rgb(128, 0, 30);">Precio: '.$precio.'</span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(128, 0, 30);">
<a href="agregar_carrito.php" class="button">Comprar</a></span></p>
</div>
<!-- SEPARADOR-->
';
     }elseif($cont==4){
      echo'
      <!-- SEPARADOR-->
       <div class="layout-cell layout-item-3" style="width: 25%" >
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(128, 0, 30);">
<img width="100" height="77" alt="" class="lightbox" src="'.$imgproductosruta.$imagen.'">
<br></span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(128, 0, 30);">
'.$descrip.'...
<br></span></p><p style="text-align: center;">
<span style="color: rgb(128, 0, 30);">Precio: '.$precio.'</span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(128, 0, 30);">
<a href="agregar_carrito.php" class="button">Comprar</a></span></p>
</div>
<!-- SEPARADOR-->
      </div></div></div>
      '; 
      $cont=1;
     }else{
       echo'
       <!-- SEPARADOR-->
       <div class="layout-cell layout-item-3" style="width: 25%" >
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(128, 0, 30);">
<img width="100" height="77" alt="" class="lightbox" src="'.$imgproductosruta.$imagen.'">
<br></span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(128, 0, 30);">
'.$descrip.'...
<br></span></p><p style="text-align: center;">
<span style="color: rgb(128, 0, 30);">Precio: '.$precio.'</span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(128, 0, 30);">
<a href="agregar_carrito.php" class="button">Comprar</a></span></p>
</div>
<!-- SEPARADOR-->
';
     }
    $cont++;

    }
    if($la<3 || $cont<4){echo'</div></div></div>';}
}else{echo'No hay ningun producto registrado';}
```

Comment: everything seems okay when i paste this in a file and check for php errors (php -l test.php). is this the whole content of /home/falconim/public_html/ucsg/tdg2/productos.php ?

Comment: Which line is line 20.

Comment: This can't be the entire file. For starters, where is the opening `<?php` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close your last if and then try to else it.

```
if($la<3 || $cont<4){echo'</div></div></div>';}
}else{echo'No hay ningun producto registrado';}
```

Should be

```
if($la<3 || $cont<4){echo'</div></div></div>';
}else{echo'No hay ningun producto registrado';}
```